# Push notifications with firebase on Android do not arrive from POSTMAN

Tags: android, ionic-framework, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, postman

I have a problem, if I send a notification with the option to send a test message from the Firebase console, it arrives immediately, even with the app (android) closed or in the background. But, if I send it from postman it takes a while to arrive, the message is lost or it simply does not arrive. Rregards!!!

How can I send a notification that arrives immediately, even with the app closed or the phone locked? the app in Ionic+Angular+Capacitor already works because from the console it works fine, this is the code I use in postman:

*In Headers:*
Content -Type application/json
Authorization key=

*in body:*
"to":"",
"notification": {
"title": "title notification",
"body": "DEMO TEXT !!",
"OrganizationId": "1",
"content_available": true,
"priority": "high",
"subtitle": "Sending app",
"timeToLive": "1"

},
"data": {
"priority": "high",
"sound": "app_sound.wav",
"content_available": true,
"bodyText": "New Announcement assigned",
"organization": "DOS",
"timeToLive": "1"

},
}

*Method POST to:  https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send*

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When sending from the firebase console the notification arrives without problem, almost immediately (2-3 seconds) and with the phone locked, without problem, but I have not been able to do this function from postman. Is it another function that I should invoke or should I use some library? From postman I receive without problem when the phone is newly locked or unlocked, there I receive the message in 2 seconds, I already tried with the phone on a different network than the computer, setting high priority, removing it, I don't know if postman uses a REST that does not activate and have to use the sdk in nodeJS for example.

[Console FireBase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTEKs.png)

Greetings and thanks for any help you can provide me.